# how to convert integer variable into QTime object

Tags: c++, qt, casting

i'm seriously new to this QT stuff. this may be a silly question but i couldn't find any answer for that. I have gone through qt documentation and searched internet to find answer to this question.

my question is that suppose there is an "integer variable" which has a duration value in seconds. I need that one to convert into QTime object to return as a QTime. How can I do this in Qt creator??..

```
int seekTime;
int seconds = QTime().secsTo(duration);
seekTime = seconds * bytePos/totalSize;
return seekTime;
```

i need to return this seekTime variable as a QTime object how can I do this?

thanx in advance..!

Comment: When you construct your QTime object `QTime::QTime ( int h, int m, int s = 0, int ms = 0 )`  put in 0 for hours and 0 for minutes..

Comment: @drescherjm I think your answer is the solution to the problem, but can u describe it further how can i actually do this I got errors when I tried this.\

Comment: No - This only works when the seconds are less than 60 seconds - From Qt docu: "h must be in the range 0 to 23, m and s must be in the range 0 to 59, and ms must be in the range 0 to 999."

Comment: So you could calculate how many hours, minutes and seconds your "duration" has, split it and then use the constuctor in that way.

Comment: @TWE thanx Yeah I  saw it later..first I thought it correct bcoz i just skimmed the docx..but after I saw it..thanx anyway.\

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
QTime t = QTime().addSecs(duration);
```

Here's a small program I tried:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <QTime>

int main()
{
   int durationInSeconds = 40;
   QTime t = QTime().addSecs(durationInSeconds);
   std::cout << "h: " << t.hour() << ", m: " << t.minute() << " s: " << t.second() << ", ms: " << t.msec() << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

This is the output I got:

```
h: 0, m: 0 s: 40, ms: 0
```

**Update**

A `QTime` can also be constructed to represent the seconds as:

```
int durationInSeconds = 40;
QTime t(0, 0, durationInSeconds);
```

**Update 2**

The function `secsTo` can be used to compute the difference in seconds between two instances of `QTime`. Here's the documentation:

> **int QTime::secsTo ( const QTime & t ) const**
>
> Returns the number of seconds from this time to t. If t is earlier than this time, the number of seconds returned is negative.
>
> Because QTime measures time within a day and there are 86400 seconds in a day, the result is always between -86400 and 86400.
>
> secsTo() does not take into account any milliseconds.

Say you have:

```
QTime t1(0, 1, 0:
QTime t2(0, 0, 45);

int secs = t2.secsTo(t1); // secs should be equal to 15.
secs = t1.secsTo(t2);     // secs should be equal to -15.
```

Hope that clarifies the intended behaviour of `QTime::secsTo` a little bit.

Comment: no I don't need to add seconds. it add duration to the t. i just need to convert what already has.

Comment: sorry for ur effort but no i've tried that.its not the answer i seeked..do you know how can it done by using the constructor by any chance??

Comment: @Mlarnt90, See my update. Hopefully that works for you.

Comment: This works as long as seconds doesn't exceed 59, otherwise an invalid `QTime` is created. I think that the only possible solution here is to use the returned difference in seconds to calculate the hours and minutes yourself.